# How to restrict media library grid view to only display files from categories current role has access to

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I am building a plugin where users can only see Media files from categories which are accessible by User role assigned to him.

I have been able to filter out the result in **media list view mode**, when it first loads by hooking a function to `pre_get_posts` action, but don't know how to do the same for grid view mode.

This is what happening:

`User-A` is assigned to `Role-A` which has access to categories `Cat-A` and `Cat-B`.

When User-A logs in to the admin and navigates to Media list view page, correct media files are coming up, i.e. only from Cat-A and Cat-B. But on Media grid view mode, all media files are coming up, while I want medias only from above two categories to appear.

I searched the web and looked into some posts in Stack Overflow but did not find what I am exactly looking for.

### Edit

After more searching I have found this:

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/ajax_query_attachments_args

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', array( $this, 'load_media_library_by_category_access' ), 10, 1 );

function load_media_library_by_category_access( $query = array() ) {
   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
   if( $user_id ) {
      $query['author'] = $user_id;
   }

   return $query;
}
```

Since the above is possible, is this also possible to find categories attached to each media item and then create a filtered array consisting of media items associated with given categories?

Something like:

```
function load_media_library_by_category_access( $query = array() ) {

   // Get an array of category ids, which I already have
   $cat_array = get_category_array_by_role();

   // Modify $query to filter media items by given categories (array may be?)

   return $query;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204779/how-can-i-add-an-author-filter-to-the-media-library) it's not possible for the Grid View.  You can only manipulate the media results for the list view.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Meanwhile I have got something which looks promising. If you please look at my updated question and advice me that would be a great help!

Comment: @SubrataSarkar that AJAX hook will only modify the media library pop-up window.

Comment: Oh! Its really strange why they don't have this for grid view!!

Comment: @SubrataSarkar yes sorry it won't be possible.  If you could award me some points for assisting you that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work finally. This is how I did it:

```
function load_media_library_by_category_access( $query = array() ) {

    $cats = $this->get_accessible_categories();

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cats,
        ),
    );

    if( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
        $query['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
    }

    return $query;
}


add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', array($this, 'load_media_library_by_category_access'), 10, 1);
```

Now my media grid view filters out correct media items based on categories that current user role has access to.

Since `administrator` does not need to be restricted I put the following check before actually injecting the `$tax_query` filter into original query.

```
if( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
    $query['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
}
```

Thought this might be helpful for others.

Comment: Hmm interesting I'll take a look at it but everything on the web suggested that hook would not do what you wanted....

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', 'show_current_user_attachments', 10, 1 );
 
function show_current_user_attachments( $query = array() ) {
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($query);
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( $user_id ) {
        //$query['author'] = $user_id;
    }
    $query['post_mime_type'] = 'image';
    return $query;
}
```